# Are Apps built with Appilix or something similar allowed on Google PlayStore

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have a website. I want an app to go with it. I noticed there are tools like Appilix which will reduce development time/cost for Website based apps by a lot. But I have also heard Google PlayStore doesn't like apps built that way. So I want to confirm if that is the case because I definitely want it to be put on PlayStore.

I searched Google Communities and questions on stackoverflow but couldn't find answer to my question

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with Appilix for last 2 years and I can assure you that if your website does not have any inappropriate content, then your App will surely be approved into Google Play Store.

In Appilix, every day, hundreds of apps are built and published into Google Play Store without any issues.
Also, it's Appilix's policy, if your app got rejected into Play Store, you will get full refunds